# Iphone compile warning

Tags: iphone, compilation

im compiling my app , which is working great and i wanted to ask you 2 questions 
1. im getting about 14 warnings like that

> no '-addCategory' method found

which i know how to solve but even after i cleaned everything added the function to the header file and compile again it's still there i cant get rid of it.
2. im pretty new in coding and the code is not GREAT but it's ok how do i know apple will accept it ?

thank you very much !!

Comment: Can you please post some of your .h and .m file which is using this function?

Comment: You don't submit your code to Apple, you submit a built app. As for their acceptance policy, there's no guarantee they will accept anything, but as long as your app doesn't crash, doesn't leak memory, and is deemed "generally useful", it should be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare that method in .h file
Implement that method in .m [implementor of .h] file .with the same signature.
Clean in once.
And try..
It should work..!

Comment: http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/objective-c-python-ruby-development/13584-warning-method-definition-not-found.html